# NameError Exception: uninitialized constant User::CustomFieldDatum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I am trying a `polymorphic association` between tables. I have this in my User model.

user.rb

```
 has_many :custom_field_data, as: :customizable
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :customizable
```

custom_field_data.rb

```
class CustomFieldData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customizable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :custom_field
end
```

when I am trying to build `@user` attribute in `users_controller` like this:

```
def new
  @user = @current_company.users.build
  @customizable = @user.customizable.build
end
```

its throwing me an error:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `customizable' for #<User:0x000000045dbe58>):
 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `new'
```

when I am trying to access `@user.custom_field_data`, I am getting this:

```
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant User::CustomFieldDatum
```

I don't know, where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried reloading your console or server?

Comment: Yes, I have tried everything..!!!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using gem files. once again bundle it

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

this issue is because of you have wrong model name(plural) i.e CustomFieldData, it should   be CustomFieldDatum, because data is a plural word, and Datum is singular.

so to fix it specify class name along with association in user model.

```
has_many :custom_field_data, as: :customizable, class_name: 'CustomFieldData'
```